# What does 散々見てた means in this sentence?

Tags: expressions, japanese-to-english

> 掻き込んで食べるのは、**散々見てた**けれども

Is this "rarely saw" or "I saw many times"? Much appreciate if someone can explain to me the correct meaning here o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the latter. The sentence means "I've seen (scenes like this) many times". It can have an accusatory overtone, so something like "more than enough times" may be better.

散々 rarely means "(spatially) dispersed" in modern Japanese, and it never means "occasionally/rarely".